# Cannot build Next.js project with next-auth

Tags: typescript, next.js, build, next-auth

I am getting the below error:

```
> next build

   Linting and checking validity of types ..Failed to compile.
./node_modules/next-auth/src/core/errors.ts:11:11
Type error: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(message?: string, options?: ErrorOptions): Error', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | Error' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'Error' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(message?: string): Error', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | Error' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'Error' is not assignable to type 'string'.

   9 |   constructor(error: Error | string) {
  10 |     // Support passing error or string
> 11 |     super((error as Error)?.message ?? error)
     |           ^
  12 |     this.name = "UnknownError"
  13 |     this.code = (error as any).code
  14 |     if (error instanceof Error) {
```

When tryingto build my next.js project.

I am using:

- node `v18.12.1`
- yarn `v1.22.19`
- next.js `v13.5.2`
- typescript `v4.8.4`

I played around with different versions of typescript, next.js, next-auth but it doesn't help. I wonder if a version of some package I'm using is incompatible or it's just a next-auth issue.

Comment: I managed to get the build to pass by downgrading `next-auth` to `~4.20.1` for now

Comment: You don't need to play around with different versions of typescript, next.js and next-auth. Keep the latest version as is. 

As well as upgrade your node version to v18.18.0 LTS. Why?

Because I have recently built a next.js project. No error at all from the next-auth.